# How to recover files from a healthy microSD card that is accessible only from an unrooted Android smartphone?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, file-recovery

I accidentally deleted important documents (about 100 PDFs) that weren't backed up yet from a 64 GB microSD card, which is used as the primary storage in my unrooted Android 9.0 smartphone. The microSD card is not encrypted and quite new, but for some reason, I've never been able to access the card from *any* PC when plugged into a card reader - only through the smartphone or when the phone is connected to the PC via USB and only using the MTP protocol. Under Windows, I always get the error message that the card needs to be formatted first.

After the accidental deletion, the microSD card was immediately removed from the phone, so I'm fairly certain that the files are still "healthy". I hope Android and SD cards work the same way as other OSs and common file systems in that normal deletion does not physically remove the data from the storage device, but only from the file table (please correct me if I'm wrong).

QUESTION: **How can I restore my deleted files? Also, is there a way to get RAW access from a PC?**

Any idea why I can access the card only via the MTP protocol from Windows?

For hard drives/storage devices accessible from a Windows or Linux PC, I've been using several recovery programs with mixed success in the past, e.g. Piriform's [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/de-de/recuva), CGSecurity's [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), and recently also [RecuperaBit](https://github.com/Lazza/RecuperaBit). I do have the Android SDK platform tools installed and have used ADB before to uninstall apps etc. if that helps. But I have zero experience with this data recovery problem on Android - and I'm also confused why e.g. Windows won't read the card's contents when connected via a card reader.

---

*Small correction:* My poor choice of words seems to have caused some confusion. By

> used as the "primary storage"

I didn't mean to say that Android is running the system partitions (`boot`, `system`, `data` etc.) on the SD card instead of the internal memory. Rather, all apps are set to store their data on the SD card if possible in order to prevent irretrievable data loss in case of a phone brick. This is due to very bad past experiences with Android's security architecture, which is basically a trap waiting to lock users out of their own data.

Furthermore, I can confirm that SD card encryption is an optional setting in my Samsung's Android 9.0 and has **not** been turned on. Hence, the SD card ought to be unencrypted!

Sorry for not being clearer.

---

UPDATE: As per request, here is a screenshot of [DMDE](https://dmde.com) showing partition information.

[image: DMDE screenshot]

Comment: Windows cannot read Linux filesystems (without additional drivers/software). Try Linux, but create a bit-by-bit copy ("disk image") of the SD card first.

Comment: @DanielB Hi, thanks for your advice. Do you mean I should use `dd` to copy the whole card to disk and then work on this copy instead of the card? And how to proceed from there?

Comment: explain 'mixed results' please. were you or were you not able to recover files using the tools tried?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Sorry, I meant that I have a bit of experience with these tools working on hard drives, USB sticks etc. under Windows. With the microSD card now, unfortunately, I'm not even able to access it in Windows (will try Linux next)

Comment: but as long as the physical card is detected you should be able to photorec for example.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Unfortunately not, just tried it before posting here

Comment: I don't data recovery from phones, but  have colleagues who do so I pick up stuff sometimes. AFAIK if microSD is configured as internal memory it's encrypted. Try/show partitions TAB for the card in DMDE.

Comment: `The microSD card is not encrypted` I kinda doubt that. AFAIR adoptable storage is always encrypted.

Comment: I doubt it too. Assuming primary storage means internal storage: Android encrypts internal storage, no ways around it. configuring microSD as internal storage will encrypt it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Sorry for the confusion, but the SD card is **not** encrypted. I meant to say that I'm storing as much data as possible on the SD card in order to keep it "out of the reach" of Android's encryption, which has caused several incidents of complete data loss for me (with Android, the *slightest* software or hardware issue can lock users out of their own data). I've added an erratum to the question.

Comment: @TomYan Sorry, but there is a misunderstanding. Please see comment above and clarification in the question text

Comment: Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250871/44325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main obstacle was the old card reader that couldn't handle the large (64 GB) microSD card. After buying a new **SDXC**-enabled card reader, I was able to get the card's content displayed in Windows 10 and subsequently restore all deleted files using [DMDE](https://dmde.com) as suggested by @JoepvanSteen. Since the card was immediately removed from the smartphone after accidental deletion, all files could be restored in 100% condition. Many thanks for the helpful suggestions!

Comment: Good to hear you got the files back!

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Yeah, DMDE worked great. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The file system on the card is most likely an EXT4 filesystem, which explains why it cant be read in Windows (without software).

That said, if yoy did delete the files just viewing the filesystem likely wont help.   You probably want to use software like Photorec (for Linux)/or Recuva to attempt partial recovery (ie of unfragmented files, and no filenames.

My first step would be to do a bitcopy of the drive (using ddrescue under Linux) so I am dealing with a copy of the drive im case it gets screwed up worse.

If you are lucky, you may be able to recover files more completely using https://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this and report back!

Comment: Hi, I've got a new, SDXC-enabled card reader and can finally confirm that the file system is actually FAT/exFAT (see DMDE screenshot in question). The card's content also get immediately displayed in Windows 10 now

Answer (score 0):

> 64 GB microSD card, which is used as the primary storage

Assuming this means 'internal storage':

Android encrypts internal storage (modern versions). Configuring a microSD to be used as internal storage means it will be encrypted.

This means you can not read or recover data from the card outside the phone.

Alternatively the microSD card can be configured as portable storage. So question is, was the microSD configured as internal or portable storage?

See for example: [https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/47282/~/microsd-card%3A-adoptable-storage-on-android](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/47282/%7E/microsd-card%3A-adoptable-storage-on-android)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see erratum in question text for some clarification on encryption. But you're describing a very relevant scenario - assuming that the SD card was indeed encrypted, what would you recommend? Are there e.g. any good recovery tools that can be run from an unrooted Android and would such tool then have the necessary read access to the RAW data?

Comment: Insert card in reader >get DMDE > select card reader > show screenshot of partitions TAB please.

Comment: I've ordered a new, SDXC-capable card reader (mine appears to be too old to support large-volume cards, probably >10 years), it should arrive in 1-2 days...will post the DMDE screenshot shortly!

Comment: Always a good idea to swap out hardware!

Comment: I ordered [this](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0BGNZGDTC) one (Beikell B6311) due to its compact size, full aluminum body, and okay reviews. Hope it's okay...

Comment: Hi, the card reader finally arrived and works like a charm, the microSD card gets immediately displayed in Windows 10. I've added a screenshot of DMDE to the question. The software looks very professional, but there are many options I'm not sure how to set